# Parse C-style format strings in python

Tags: python, c, string, format-string

Let's say a format string is given as `export_%05u.png`, we can create a full string in python by supplying an integer like this `s = "export_%05u.png"%1`. But If we have the format string and actual string, is it possible to extract the integer somehow?

Formally, these are given: `export_%05u.png` and `export_00111.png` and we need to extract 111.

Comment: It depends, for example, '%u1%u" is not reversible.

Comment: If the format string has only one `%` conversion, then match the literal characters in the format string to the actual string, remove them from the actual string, and then interpret the remaining characters as the appropriate type.

Comment: Maybe try Python regular expressions???

Comment: If you are looking only for the number within the string, try re.search('[0-9]+', s)

Comment: For a table that maps `scanf` ("`printf`") tokens to regular expressions, see the [documentation for the re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#simulating-scanf).

Comment: regex & replacing literal characters is one way, but if python has a built-in method to do this, I'd prefer that instead.